# Bootstrap renewal

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Is bootstrap 2.1.1 too early a version? Should I update to latest version 2.3.2?

I just found a wordpress theme that has bootstrap applied to it. I am unsure as to if it is imperative to update it.

I will be using the theme to do a small microsite with a maximum of 2 templates.

Comment: Subjective, but I am also interested.  Bootstrap is currently on version 3-RC1.  The stable version is 2.3.2, but personally I am holding off using any bootstrap until version 3 is stable.

Comment: If you are using a theme why would you need to upgrade TBS? If you are creating a theme use this: http://www.rootstheme.com/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses a major.minor.patch versioning system.

A jump from version 2.x.x to version 3.x.x represents a break in backwards compatibility. A jump from 2.1.x to 2.2.x represents new features and enhancements. A jump from version 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 represents fixes to bugs and errors.

That's not a direct answer to your question, but hopefully gives you the information you need to make an educated decision on whether or not to upgrade.